# Scope issue using records in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, scope, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, records

I am trying to use data from a record inside an execute statement:

```
for rec1 in  SELECT * FROM table1 limit 1000 loop

    FOR loop_row IN
                    select 'geom_wgs_pois5' as col_name
          union all select 'geom_wgs_pois4' as col_name
          union all select 'geom_wgs_pois3' as col_name
          union all select 'geom_wgs_pois2' as col_name
          union all select 'geom_wgs_pois1' as col_name

    LOOP
    select rec1.loop_row into query;
    v_sql = 'select count(*)
             from   table2 a
             where  a.'||loop_row||' = '||query||'';
    execute $$v_sql$$;
    ..........
```

I have tried to put the record directly into v_sql, but I believe that there are scope issues with this.  When I try to use the select statement to "unpack" the record, I also get errors.

This method where I create the query in an string then use an execute statement is done on purpose.  I have made the same function using other methods, but they are too slow.  To improve performance, I am trying to reference a table with more columns to avoid using a lot of string operations in my queries.

I am running on a postgres 8.2.15.  I know this is old and that I should upgrade, but it is what my company has provided to me (hence, I have no choice in the matter).

Answer (score 0):

There is not possibility to compare REC in dynamic SQL in PostgreSQL 8.2. You need minimally PostgreSQL 8.4 where you should to use a clause `USING`. In 8.2 you have to manually compare all fields in record.

There is workaround, but I am not sure about performance. You can create temporary table with record value, and then in dynamic SQL you can do `JOIN` with your table.